# ArrayList<Double> insertion(java)

Tags: java, arraylist

how should i insert a double into a specific part of ArrayList?
for example we have a ArrayList with ten doubles each one with the 0 value we want to  make the sixth place 10, how should we do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use `ArrayList.set()` method:

```
public E set(int index,
             E element)

Replaces the element at the specified position in this list
with the specified element.
```

For example:

```
list.set(5, new Double(10));
```

Comment: list doesn't have `set` method.

Comment: @adashr See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29)

Comment: @adarshr, yes i does: `public E set(int index,
             E element)Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element. `

Comment: Ok I take back the downvote. But the OP wanted to insert, not replace.

Comment: @adarshr, I think the OP does want to replace as all it is stated that there is already an ArrayList with ten doubles, all with value zero.

Comment: OP wants to set not insert new one,_value we want to make the sixth place 10_

Comment: Oh yes indeed, you guys are right. It must be one of those days :(

Comment: This is the correct way, but I wouldn't use `new Double(10)` instead use `Double.valueOf(10)`

Answer (score 1):

Just used the indexed `add`.

```
list.add(6, 10D);
```

**EDIT:**

But if you want to *replace* the value at the specified index (instead of inserting a new one), I suggesst you follow [@hmjd's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10430225/343955) solution.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

```
void add(int index, Object element);
```

Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.